# Correctly terminating a thread in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm not too familiar with threading, and probably not using it correctly, but I have a script that runs a speedtest a few times and prints the average. I'm trying to use threading to call a function which displays something while the tests are running.

Everything works fine unless I try to put input() at the end of the script to keep the console window open. It causes the thread to run continuously.
I'm looking for some direction in terminating a thread correctly. Also open to any better ways to do this.

```
import speedtest, time, sys, datetime
from threading import Thread

s = speedtest.Speedtest()
best = s.get_best_server()

def downloadTest(tries):
    x=0
    downloadList = []
    for x in range(tries):
        downSpeed = (s.download()/1000000)
        downloadList.append(downSpeed)
        x+=1
        results_dict = s.results.dict()
    global download_avg, isp
    download_avg = (sum(downloadList)/len(downloadList))
    download_avg = round(download_avg,1)
    isp = (results_dict['client']['isp'])
    print("")
    print(isp)
    print(download_avg)

def progress():
    while True:
        print('~ ',end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)


def start():
    now=(datetime.datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0))            
    print(now)
    d = Thread(target= downloadTest, args=(3,))
    d.start()
    d1 = Thread(target = progress)
    d1.daemon = True
    d1.start()
    d.join()

start()
input("Complete...") # this causes progress thread to keep running
```

Comment: Are you deliberately not killing d1 after d finishes?

Comment: I set d1 as a daemon so it terminates when d dies. It does this correctly without the input on the last line

Comment: How do I deliberately terminate d correctly?

Comment: `d` will terminate correctly because you're `join`ing it and it's not an infinite loop. If you type in some input when it gets to complete and hits return, does the program then terminate as expected? Or it get's stuck *after* the input statement with d1 printing progress forever?

Comment: It does stop after I input something. Which I guess makes sense. My goal is just to keep the console open after the test finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for your thread to exit, which is why it does not terminate. A daemon thread normally terminates when your programm (all other threads) terminate, which does not happen in this as the last input does not quit.

In general it is a good idea to make a thread stop by itself, rather than forcefully killing it, so you would generally kill this kind of thread with a flag. Try changing the segment at the end to:

```
killflag = False
start()
killflag = True
input("Complete...")
```

and update the progress method to:

```
def progress():
    while not killflag:
        print('~ ',end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That does it. Thank you so much